Asymptotic Expansion of a Recurrence Relation Involving a Square Root
I'm working on analyzing the asymptotic behavior of a sequence defined as follows:
$$
u_0 \geq 0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad u_{n + 1} = \sqrt{u_{n} + n^{2}} \quad \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
I've already observed the following:

If $u_{0} = 0$, it's easy to show that
$n \leq u_{n} \leq n + 1$, which implies
$$
u_n \sim n\quad \mbox{as}\quad n \to \infty
$$
I also believe this encadrement holds independently of the choice of $u_{0}$, provided $n$ is sufficiently large.
By introducing $v_{n} = u_{n} - n$, I can refine the asymptotic expansion further.
After substituting $u_{n} = n + v_{n}$ into the recurrence relation, I obtained:
$$
v_{n + 1} \sim-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{v_{n}}{2 n}
$$
Summing the terms iteratively, I suspect that:
$$
v_{n} \sim -\frac{1}{2}\,\ln\left(n\right) + C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant depending on the initial value $u_{0}$.
Thus, I conjecture that the asymptotic expansion of $u_{n}$ to three terms is:
$$
u_{n} \sim n -\frac{1}{2}\,\ln\left(n\right) + C
$$
Question:
How can I systematically extend this to obtain a three-term asymptotic expansion for $u_{n}$ ?.

I'd appreciate any feedback, insights, or references to similar problems.
Thanks in advance !.

$$
u_n  \sim n - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{{8n}} - \frac{3}{{8n^2 }} - \frac{{81}}{{128n^3 }} +  \ldots
$$

Your result $u_n \sim n-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{8 n}-\frac{3}{8 n^2}-\frac{81}{128 n^3}+\ldots$ is very interesting! I'm curious to know the reasoning that led you to this detailed asymptotic expansion.
Did you use a specific method, such as a classical asymptotic expansion or another analytical approach? If possible, could you share some key steps or main ideas from your process?

I just showed that if an asymptotic expansion of that form exists, its first several coefficients must be those shown.

Step 1.
$$n - 1 \le u_{n} \le n + u_0$$
for all $n$, as can be seen by an induction argument.
Step 2.
$$
\begin{align*}
u_{n+1} &= n\sqrt{\frac{u_n}{n^2} + 1}\\
&=n\left(1 + \frac{u_n}{2n^2} + O(1/n^2)\right),
\end{align*}
$$
Here, the expansion is valid with the implicit constant uniform in $n$, assuming that $\frac{u_n}{n^2} < \frac{1}{2}$. The latter condition is true for $n$ sufficiently large by step 1.
It follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
u_{n+1} - n &= \frac{u_n}{2n} + O(1/n)
\end{align*}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\begin{align*}
v_{n+1}  &= \frac{v_n}{2n} -\frac{1}{2} + O(1/n).
\end{align*}
$$
By step 1,
$$
-\frac{1}{n} \le {\frac{v_n}{n}} \le \frac{u_0}{n}
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{v_n}{n} = 0.
$$
It follows by the result of step 2 that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} {v_n}= -\frac{1}{2}.
$$

This answer use the same bound as in my answer, and use more complicated notations/asymptotics. I wonder what this answer adds to the previous answer?

@LNT The previous answer did not have the asymptotic for $v_n$ when I posted my answer.

OK, it would have been better to comment in my answer since the asymptotic for $v_n$ is clearly immediate (I just added without noticing that).

@LNT well, "immediate" is relative and furthermore this answer gives more information on the size of the error $u_n - n + \frac{1}{2} = O(1/n^3)$.

I believe the size of error is $O(1/n)$, from your expansion of $(1+x)^{1/2}$, note that $u_n/n \rightarrow 1$, so it should be $O(1/n^2)$ there instead of $O(1/n^4)$

@LNT you're right, thanks for pointing that out.

After further calculations, I found the following asymptotic expansion for $u_n$ :
$$
u_n=n-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{8 n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
I’d like to confirm if this result is correct

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I write a possible answer here. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.
We can prove by induction that $n \leq u_{n+1} \leq n+1 + u_0, \forall n \geq 0$. First, let's check $n=0$, $$u_1 = \sqrt{u_0+0^2} = \sqrt{u_0} \leq 1 + u_0 $$
Suppsoe it's true for $n$, we prove this is true for $n+1$. Indeed,
$$ u^2_{n+1} = u_n +n^2 \leq n+u_0 + n^2 \leq (n+1+u_0)^2, $$
hence $u_{n+1} \leq n+1 +u_0$, completing the induction steps. So $u_n$~ $n$.
From this, you can even get
$$ u_{n+1} - n = \frac{u_n}{\sqrt{u_n+n^2}+n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}. $$
Does this answer your question?
